# Can we obtain min $\mathbf{x}$ in $\Vert A - B(I\otimes \mathbf{x})\Vert_F^2$ algebraically?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, trace, kronecker-product, frobenius-method

Are we able to obtain the following algebraically?$$\widehat{\mathbf{x}}=\underset{\mathbf{x}}{\operatorname{argmin}}\|A-B(I\otimes \mathbf{x})\|_F^2$$where
$A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $B\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times (m\cdot n)}$, $I\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is the identity, $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times 1}$, and $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product. If it helps, $m<n$.

Let $f_{(\mathbf{x})}=\|A-B(I\otimes \mathbf{x})\|_F^2$ and $\operatorname{tr}(\cdot )$ be the trace function, then\begin{align*}f_{(\mathbf{x})} & =\operatorname{tr}\left (A^tA\right )+\operatorname{tr}\left ((I\otimes \mathbf{x})^tB^tB(I\otimes \mathbf{x})\right )-2\operatorname{tr}\left (A^tB(I\otimes \mathbf{x})\right ) \\
& =\operatorname{tr}\left ((I\otimes \mathbf{x})(I\otimes \mathbf{x})^tB^tB\right ) -2\operatorname{tr}\left ((I\otimes \mathbf{x})A^tB\right )+\operatorname{constant}.
\end{align*}I'm stuck at proceeding beyond this step to find the derivative of the function with respect to $\mathbf{x}$. I have referred to tools like the [Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) but couldn't find the derivative structure.

Please help with this problem if it can be solved algebraically (not numerically).
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use the Kronecker product construction for matrix multiplication and regularize suitably.

Comment: @mathreadler, can you please provide more information on 'regularize suitably'? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I will try composing an answer tomorrow. Today is nice fishing weather.

Comment: @mathreadler, :)

Answer (score 2):

The systematic approach to use here is to define the operations with [Kronecker products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) ($\otimes$) working on vectorizations ($\text{vec}$).

First let us split the problem into two:

1. Express  $({\bf R}\otimes {\bf x})$ as a matrix operator multiplying on $\bf x$ : $({\bf R}\otimes {\bf x})=\bf M_{R\otimes} x$.
2. Express the subsequent multiplication by $\bf B$ as a matrix operator : $\bf M_{L(B)}$. Notation meaning : (M)ultiply from the (L)eft by $\bf B$.

With these things together we can reformulate :

$${\bf \hat x} = \underset{\mathbf{x}}{\operatorname{argmin}}\|{\bf A}-{\bf M_{L(B)}} {\bf M_{I\otimes}} {\bf x}\|_F^2$$

Realizing we can consider $\bf M = M_{L(B)} M_{I\otimes}$ a new matrix now we have an ordinary least squares problem:

$${\bf \hat x} = \underset{\mathbf{x}}{\operatorname{argmin}}\|{\bf A}-{\bf M} {\bf x}\|_F^2$$

The link to Kronecker products shall help you solve 2 so I will focus on solving 1 in the remainder of this answer.

I will not make a proof, but make a numerical demonstration with some Octave code

```
N = [5,4];
B = rand(2,prod(N));
R = rand(N(1));
x = rand(N(2),1);

M_2 = kron(R(:),eye(N(2)));
M_1 = kron(eye(5),B);

err = norm(M_1*M_2*x - vec(B*kron(R,x)))
```

Gives me $err \approx 1.2\cdot 10^{-15}$

Which is reasonable given that we use random numbers in [0,1] and double precision calculations.

Now we have transformed the problem to a usual linear least squares but maybe using a slightly bigger matrix than we might be used to.

Comment: Great, thank you! :)

Comment: You lost me at Step 1.  If $I$ is $(n\times n)$ and $x$ is $(m\times 1)$, then the Kronecker product $(I\otimes x)$ is $(mn\times n)$. What are the dimensions of the matrix $M_{I\otimes}$ such that the matrix product $(M_{I\otimes}x)$ produces an  $(mn\times n)$ result? Or by "matrix operator" do you mean some sort of tensor?

Comment: @greg That is where vectorization comes into play. The result of the multiplication will be a vectorization of the matrix we want to consider, not the matrix itself. It is the same idea of why we can represent matrix-matrix multiplication linearly as matrix-vector multiplication using the Kronecker product as explained on the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 1):

[Vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) the matrices which appear in the Frobenius norm, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
&{\rm vec}(A) = a \\
&{\rm vec}\Big(B(I_n\otimes x)\Big)
 &= (I_n\otimes B)\,{\rm vec}(I_n\otimes x) \\
 &&= (I_n\otimes B)\Big({\rm vec}(I_n)\otimes I_m\Big)x \\
 &&= Mx \\
}$$
Write the norm in terms of these vectors,
then calculate its gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 \lambda &= (Mx-a)^T(Mx-a) \\
\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x}
  &= 2M^T(Mx-a) \\
}$$
Set the gradient to zero and solve for the optimal $x$
$$\eqalign{
M^TMx &= M^Ta \\
x &= (M^TM)^{-1}M^Ta \\
  &= M^+a \qquad\big({\rm pseudoinverse}\big) \\
}$$

Comment: Yes, the matrices you arrived at are complicated. I will check it out though. Thanks so much for the contribution.

Comment: I was able to simplify the result to a linear equation.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following, define $W=I\otimes x$ and $h(W)=||A-BW||_{F}^{2}$. Now doing $f(V)= ||V||_{F}^{2}$ and $g(W) = A-BW$ then $h(W)=f \circ g(W)$. Now calculating the Jacobian for $f$ and $g$ we would have:
$$ J_{W}(g) = - B\hbox{ and } J_{V}(f)=2V^{\top}.$$
And now calculate the Jacobian for $h(w)$ using the chain rule:
$$J_{W}(f\circ g)=J_{g(W)}(f)J_{W}(g)=-2(A-BW)^{\top}B = 2(BW - A)^{\top} B.$$
Since the function $h(W)$ is convex, surely the minimun is found when $J_{W}(f\circ g)=0$. Then I would solve for $W$ like this:
$$2(BW - A)^{\top} B = 0 \Rightarrow B^{\top}(BW - A) = 0^{\top} \Rightarrow B^{\top}BW = B^{\top}A.$$
Assuming $B^{\top}B$ is invertible then:
$$W = (B^{\top}B\big)^{-1}B^{\top}A \Rightarrow I\otimes x = (B^{\top}B)^{-1}B^{\top}A.$$
From the last equation we would obtain the components of $ x $.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. However, $B^TB$ is not invertible since $B$ has more columns than rows.
 
The solution from your approach *seems to be* the least-squares problem $A \approx Bw$ which solves as $w\Rightarrow I\otimes \mathbf{x} = B^+A$ where $B^+=B^T(BB^T)^{-1}$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse, assuming $B$ has linearly independent rows.

Comment: Meanwhile, $I\otimes \mathbf{x}$ has $\mathbf{x}$ on its diagonals (block-wise) and all other entries zero. The challenge here is that the least-squares solution $w\ne I\otimes \mathbf{x}$ since $B^+A$ does not preserve the zero-block structure. Hence, it does not seem like the way to go.

It could be possible that $\mathbf{x}$ needs to be expressed in closed-form if this problem is solvable algebraically. It's still a puzzle for me.