# Derivative of Kronecker product inside a Frobenius norm

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, optimization, trace, kronecker-product

I need help to find the derivative w.r.t. to $ X $ in the problem below:

$$ 
\min_X \Vert A - (I \otimes X) \Vert_F^2 
$$

where $A $ is a complex matrix, $ I $ is the identity matrix, and $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product.

The problem seems to be similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3809788/can-we-obtain-min-mathbfx-in-vert-a-bi-otimes-mathbfx-vert-f2-al) but the trick of using 'vec' operarator does not work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bracket term is a block-diagonal matrix
with $\mathbf{X}$ repeated along diagonal.
We can thus write
$$
\phi(\mathbf{X})
= \sum_{p=1}^P \| \mathbf{X} - \mathbf{A}_{pp} \|_F^2
$$
with $\mathbf{A}_{pp}$ the $p$-th diagonal
block matrix (same size $M\times N$ as $\mathbf{X}$),
explicitly computed as
$$
\mathbf{A}_{pp} =
\left( \mathbf{e}_p \otimes \mathbf{I}_M \right)^T
\mathbf{A}
\left( \mathbf{e}_p \otimes \mathbf{I}_N \right)
$$

The gradient is easily found as
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{X}}
= \sum_{p=1}^P \left( \mathbf{X} - \mathbf{A}_{pp} \right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\Bigg(#1\Bigg)}
\def\vecc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\sz#1{\operatorname{size}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\S{\sum_{k=1}^p}
$Let's introduce the matrix variable
$$ B = (I_p\otimes X) - A $$
as well as Frobenius product notation $(:)\,$ which is a convenient way to write the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A^*:A &= \|A\|^2_F \\
}$$
The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in such a
product to be rearranged in many different but equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A \\&= \LR{A^TC}:B \\
}$$

---

Assume that the size of the various matrix variables are
$$\eqalign{
p,p &= \sz{I_p} \\
m,n &= \sz X \\
pm,pn &= \sz A \;=\; \sz B \\
}$$
and let $e_k$ denote the $k^{th}$ column of $I_p\,\big($i.e.$\,$ the standard basis vectors for ${\mathbb R}^{p}\big).$

Use the above notation to write the objective function, then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= B^*:B \\
d\phi &= B^*:dB \\
 &= B^*:(I_p\otimes dX) \\
 &= \LR{\S(e_k\otimes I_m)^T\c{B^*}(e_k\otimes I_n)}:dX \\
 &= \LR{\S(e_k\otimes I_m)^T\Big(\c{(I_p\otimes X^*)-A^*}\Big)(e_k\otimes I_n)}:dX \\
 &= \S\BR{X^*-(e_k\otimes I_m)^TA^*(e_k\otimes I_n)}:dX \\
\grad{\phi}{X}
 &= \LR{pX^*-\S(e_k\otimes I_m)^TA^*(e_k\otimes I_n)} \\
}$$
Setting the gradient to zero (and taking its conjugate) yields
$$\eqalign{
X &= \frac 1p \, \S(e_k\otimes I_m)^TA(e_k\otimes I_n) \\\\
}$$

---

The following result was implicitly used above
$$\eqalign{
&{\S(e_k\otimes I_m)\,\c{dX}\,(e_k\otimes I_n)^T}
 &= {\S(e_k\otimes I_m)\LR{I_\o\otimes dX}(e_k\otimes I_n)^T} \\
 &&= {\S\LR{e_k\,I_\o\,e_k^T}\otimes\LR{I_m\,dX\,I_n^T}} \\
 &&= {I_p\otimes dX} \\
}$$
where $I_\o = \big[ \o \big] \in {\mathbb R}^{\o\times\o}$